# Move title attribute value to class attribute value in the HTML code

Tags: php, html, regex

We have variable `$menu` with HTML inside (there is no loop, it comes from a function).

On `echo` it gives the code like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes"><a title="one" href="#">text</a></li>
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes"><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes"><a title="three" href="#">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do:

1. get value of the `title=""` of each link, and move it to the end of parent `<li>` class.
2. remove `title=""` from each link.

Code inside variable `$menu` should become:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes one"><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes"><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li id="some-id" class="many classes three"><a href="#">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

**What is the solution?**

Comment: You will have to modify the code inside the function that generates the html. Can you show us that?

Comment: @BudgieInWA, I can't do that. Code comes from the root function of cms(can't be changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but it has worked in my testing (Regex Buddy & XAMPP) with your sample code.

```
$pattern = '/(<li [^>]*)(?:class=(?:"([^"]+)"|\'([^\']+)\'))([^>]*><a[^>]*)(?:title=(?:"([^"]+)"|\'([^\']+)\'))\s([^>]*>)(.*?<\/li>)/im';
$replace = '$1class="$2 $5"$4$7$8';

preg_replace( $pattern , $replace , $menu );
```

Comment: Does it need to? If there is no title attribute in a link, then nothing changes (as there is no title to move over to the class group).

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(<li[^>]*class=".*)("><a).*title="(.*)"(.*)
```

And replace each match using backreferences:

```
\1 \3\2\4
```

Note that this will work for your example, but you might need to modify it and make it "smarter" if you have cases such as:

```
<li id="some-id >" class="many classes"><a title="one" href="#">text</a></li>
```

Comment: This does work, but your RegExp will only work if the `title` attribute is the first one declared inside the `<a...>text</a>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to modify your HTML:

In your case if no of `li` are fixed in `$menu` then you do something like this with Simple HTML DOM Parser:

```
// Include downloaded library
include 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html( $menu );


for( $i=0 ; $i<3 ; $i++ ) {

    // Get current classes of li
    $currentClasses = $html->find('li', $i)->class;

    // Get title of link
    $linkTitle = $html->find('a', $i)->title;

    // Add link title in li classes
    $html->find('li', $i)->class = $currentClasses . ' ' . $linkTitle ;

    // Remove title attribute from link
    $html->find('a', $i)->title = null;
}


echo $html;
```

Comment: @NAVEED: Someone has been running around downvoting tons of people at random lately. My answers were hit twice by the same kid in a single day. I've voted you all back up to counter the downvotes now.

Comment: @Boltclock, how do you know it was the 'same kid'? O.o is this one of the legendary mod-tools?

Comment: @David Thomas: Just a guess. It could very well be a conspiracy between three kids instead. Or a flying starfish.

Comment: @Boltclock, valid points all. There are days I **curse** those internet-using flying starfishes... =)

Comment: @NAVEED: Ah, so that's what happened to my post too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same as with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958403/catch-first-and-last-li-inside-php-variable/3958493#3958493). Use [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$links = $xpath->query( '/ul/li/a[@title]' );
foreach($links  as $link ) {
    $classes  = $link->parentNode->getAttribute( 'class' );
    $classes .= ' ' . $link->getAttribute( 'title' );
    $link->parentNode->setAttribute( 'class', $classes );
    $link->removeAttribute( 'title' );
}
echo $dom->saveXML( $dom->documentElement );
```

Again, this assumes you are using valid XHTML. If not, you have to load the markup with `loadHTML` and change the XPath to take the added HTML skeleton into account. Be aware that this also changes what `documentElement` of the DOMDocument, so you have to pass the menu node to `saveXML` instead.