# How do I add class to first paragraph and span to first letter

Tags: php

Example

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Morbi elementum odio vel tortor adipiscing vel tempor risus ullamcorper.</p>
```

I want add class for first paragraph and add span class to the first letter

```
<p class="first-paragraph"><span class="first-letter">L</span>orem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Let me know how can be with PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch first and last <li> inside php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958403/catch-first-and-last-li-inside-php-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Morbi elementum odio vel tortor adipiscing vel tempor risus ullamcorper.</p>';

$text = substr_replace($text, '</span>', 4, 0);
$text = substr_replace($text, '<span class="first-letter">', 3, 0);
$text = substr_replace($text, ' class="first-paragraph"', 2, 0);

echo htmlspecialchars($text);
```

:-)

Comment: How to make it will replace on `<p>` only?

Comment: I got it :) `preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p$1 class="first-paragraph">', $text , 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of pure CSS3:

```
p:first-of-type {
    color: red; 
}

p:first-of-type::first-letter {
    color: blue;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/everton/vpcey/